# Datepicker Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

He puesto un datePicker para capturar una fecha como entrada del usuario, este se visualiza correctamente. Sin embargo, no captura la fecha.

```
DatePicker datePicker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
// En el método tengo lo siguiente:
fecha_numero = datePicker.getMonth()+"/"+datePicker.getYear();
Log.d("Fecha numero", fecha_numero);
```

¿Alguien puede explicarme un poco cómo funciona y si mi planteamiento es correcto?

Gracias.

Comment: El fallo era que las funciones datePicker.get...() devuelve int y la corrección es:         fecha_numero = String.valueOf(datePicker.getDayOfMonth())+"/"+String.valueOf(datePicker.getMonth()+1)+"/"+String.valueOf(datePicker.getYear())+"/";

Comment: debes usar onDateChangedListener  con lo que comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Los valores del `DatePicker` no se obtienen automaticamente, realizando esto:

```
  datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
  ...
  fecha_numero = datePicker.getMonth()+"/"+datePicker.getYear();
```

**Debe inicializar el `DatePicker` y usando `onDateChangedListener` en su método `onDateChanged()` es donde obtienes como valor entero los valores de día, mes y años que seleccionas.**

```
DatePicker datePicker;
private int anio;
private int mes;
private int dia;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Obtiene instancia de DatePickerDialog
    datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new         DatePicker.onDateChangedListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
      {
         //* Obtiene valores de la fecha seleccionada.
         anio = year;
         mes = monthOfYear;
         dia = dayOfMonth;
      }
    });

 }
```